# Xamarin: EventHandler when Share Dialog will close

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Launcher.OpenAsync and Share.RequestAsync will open asynchronously an app and they will never return anything. By that I lose the app flow which means that after calling one of those methods I cannot do anymore something.

The reason I am using the OpenAsync is to save a file on the device or on iCloud.

Is there any way to do so getting back a confirmation of it so that I can show properly a message?

Comment: What is the confirmation you want to get? From the app which you run the `Launcher.OpenAsync`? Or before you open the new app? What the is message? Does the message showing before you open the new app?

Comment: I would like to allow the user to save a file and when the file is saved I want to execute a post business logic. Even if the user has canceled I want to execute that as well. But it should be after the user will close the share window.

Comment: You could try to do the saving operations in background after you close the share window. When finsh the operation, exist the background program.